# json object list to float value pairs of coordinates

Tags: python, json

I am reading a json of US state coordinates. json format:

```
"SD":[{"y":"-104.05","x":"45.94"},{"y":"-104.05","x":"43.00"},
{"y":"-98.49","x":"42.99"},{"y":"-98.44","x":"42.92"},{"y":"-98.19","x":"42.84"},
{"y":"-98.05","x":"42.77"},{"y":"-97.97","x":"42.76"},{"y":"-97.85","x":"42.85"},
{"y":"-97.22","x":"42.85"},{"y":"-97.20","x":"42.80"},{"y":"-96.84","x":"42.71"},
{"y":"-96.62","x":"42.52"},{"y":"-96.48","x":"42.47"},{"y":"-96.62","x":"42.72"},
{"y":"-96.50","x":"43.00"},{"y":"-96.43","x":"43.13"},{"y":"-96.55","x":"43.22"},
{"y":"-96.52","x":"43.38"},{"y":"-96.61","x":"43.48"},{"y":"-96.45","x":"43.49"},
{"y":"-96.45","x":"45.29"},{"y":"-96.74","x":"45.46"},{"y":"-96.84","x":"45.61"},
{"y":"-96.58","x":"45.82"},{"y":"-96.56","x":"45.93"},{"y":"-104.05","x":"45.94"}]}
```

After I load the json, it becames:

```
[{u'y': u'-104.05', u'x': u'45.94'}, 
{u'y': u'-104.05', u'x': u'43.00'},
..., 
{u'y': u'-96.56', u'x': u'45.93'}, 
{u'y': u'-104.05', u'x': u'45.94'}]
temp = {u'y': u'-104.05', u'x': u'45.94'}
```

How do I turn it into:

```
[(-104.05,45.94), (-104.05,43.00),....., (-104.05,45.94)]
```

I have tried different using replace, format, map .. on the values. But, could turn it into the required format?

Please help.

Thanks,
Das

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `array =[{u'y': u'-104.05', u'x': u'45.94'}, {u'y': u'-104.05', u'x': u'43.00'},...,]`

```
print [(float(item["y"]), float(item["x"])) for item in array]
```

**output**

```
[(-104.05, 45.94), (-104.05, 43.0), (-98.49, 42.99),...]
```